# Single read filter csv based on 1st column values

Tags: bash, debian, awk, csv

I have a gigantic csv file that is around a GB in size. The csv's 1st column contains around 300 unique integer values. I want to process the csv once and save the output to different files based on the matching 1st column value.

I know `awk` solution to save the output to column 1 specific values.

```
for i in $column1values; do
  awk -F, -v a=$i '$1 == a' input.csv > output-$i.csv
done
```

But this solution will re-read the big csv file everytime it want to find matching column 1 value. This is inefficient considering big csv file.

**So, How can I achieve this while reading the csv file only once?**

**EDIT:**
Say my original csv file has data..

```
1,r1c2,r1c3,r1c4
1,r2c2,r2c3,r2c4
2,r3c2,r3c3,r3c4
2,r4c2,r4c3,r4c4
3,r5c2,r5c3,r5c4
3,r6c2,r6c3,r6c4
```

And I want to filter the output based on 1st column values like..

output-1.csv:

```
1,r1c2,r1c3,r1c4
1,r2c2,r2c3,r2c4
```

output-2.csv

```
2,r3c2,r3c3,r3c4
2,r4c2,r4c3,r4c4
```

output-3.csv

```
3,r5c2,r5c3,r5c4
3,r6c2,r6c3,r6c4
```

More importantly, I want to filter the output like this while reading the original big csv file only once. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{f="output-"$1".csv"; print $0 >> f; close(f)}' file
```

- `-F,` sets the delimiter to `,`.
- `f="output-"$1".csv"` sets the filename to write to
- `print $0 >> f` appends the the line to the file `f`.
- `close(f)` closes the file, because there could be too many open files (thanks to comment of @[Costas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/89144/costas))